# merge changes in a single file from multiple branches

Tags: git

I have a git repo with two divergent branches, production and v2. I'm working on a third branch with a collaborator that we're merging into called prod-merge. The idea is that v2 has a ton of feature updates and production was a series of bug fixes/patches.

So now v2 should more or less be canonical but I need to merge in the changes from my production branch.

My collaborator and I have split up the workflow such that I'm in charge of merging the 'foo' namespace and he's in charge of merging in the 'bar' namespace. Said another way, I'm responsible for merging in the production branch, foo.rb file. There are several files for each of us.

I've been playing with diff,merge,patch and am without finding a workflow that feels really solid. I'd like a three way merge to make sure I don't miss anything and then commit that merge. What's the simplest solution that could work?

thanks,
Bryce

Comment: Why not simply merge the branch with `git merge <branch>`? It sounds like each branch only edits its own namespace anyway

Comment: I don't necessarily want the whole branch, most times I just want a file or two.

Comment: There are solutions to that (`checkout --theirs` vs `--ours` vs `--conflict`), but it's better if the branch only changes the files it's supposed to change. What happens with the other changes? This looks like something a better workflow could fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there must be a better way, but I found this to do just the trick:

`git format-patch --stdout feature..master -- app/controllers/feeds_controller.rb > ~/Desktop/feeds.patch`

`git am -3 -i --ignore-date ~/Desktop/feeds.patch`

Answer (score 0):

We have lots of very complex branches, branch ownership scenarios, etc. I've documented the approach here. Hope this gives you some good ideas.

https://plus.google.com/109096274754593704906/posts/R4qkeyRadLR